# Intersection of Quotient Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

> Suppose $X$ is a finite-dimensional linear space, $U$ and $V$ two subspaces of $X$ such that $X$ is the sum of $U$ and $V$, i.e, $X=U+V$. Denote by $W$ the intersection of $U$ and $V$, i.e., $W=U\cap V$. Define $U_0=U/W$ and $V_0=V/W$. Then $U_0 \cap V_0=\{0\}$

I do not quite understand the last sentence.

In my mind:
$U_0=\{u+W|u\in U\}$ and $V_0=\{v+W|v\in V\}$
Therefore, $U_0 \cap V_0$ can even equal to $X$ if $U=V=X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation for the quotient space is a little vague. Perhaps this description will help. The quotient space is the space obtained by shrinking the entire subspace $W$ to a single point $0$. The resulting space is $X/W$, and it is a distinct space from $X$ (it is not a subspace). So when we talk about $U_0 \cap V_0$, $U_0 = U/W$ and $V_0 = V/W$ are subspaces of $X/W$, not of $X$. Therefore we certainly could not have $U_0 \cap V_0 = X$, since $X$ is an entirely different space. The most we can ask for is $U_0 \cap V_0 = X/W$.

If you have $U = V = X$, then $W = U \cap V = X$ and $U/W = V/W = X/W = X/X = \{0\}$. So it is indeed true that $U_0 \cap V_0 = X/W$ (not $= X$), but also that $U_0 \cap V_0 = \{0\}$.

Comment: If we shrink the entire subspace $W$ to a single point $0$, then $X / W$=$\{x+0|x\in X\}=X$?

Comment: @VivianL. Let's say $W=X$. If we shrink $W$ to a single a point, we are shrinking $X$ to a single a point, so $X/W = \{0\} \neq X$

Comment: If $U_o \cap V_o \neq \{0\}$, will we still have $X/W=U_o + V_o$?

Comment: @VivianL. In the context of this question, we must have $U_0 \cap V_0 = \{0\}$.

Comment: @ Y. Forman Sorry, I mean, is $U_o\cap V_o = \{0\}$ necessary for $X/W=U_o + V_o$ being true?

Comment: @VivianL. Meaning, could $X/W = U_0 + V_0$ be true without $U_0 \cap V_0 = \{0\}$? But we must have $U_0 \cap V_0 = \{0\}$, so it's hard to know how to answer that. I'm having trouble grasping your question.